# How to rename file using substring of the same file name

Tags: command-line, command

I want to rename my file with its substring.Because unfortunately renamed all the files in my server.

*Now I want to remove suffix( .gz) of all the files including files in subdirectories also.*

Below is avaliable files with extra `.gz`.

```
# pwd
/usr/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/rdnqa/WEB-INF/classes
# ls
META-INF                           jbpm.hibernate.cfg.xml.gz          jbpm.jpdl.cfg.xml.gz               jpdl-4.0.xsd.gz
config                             jbpm.hibernate.cfg.xml.mirror.gz   jbpm.mail.templates.xml.gz         jpdl-4.2.xsd.gz
ecnet                              jbpm.hibernate.cfg.xml.staging.gz  jbpm.repository.hbm.xml.gz         jpdl-4.3.xsd.gz
hibernate.queries.hbm.xml.gz       jbpm.history.hbm.xml.gz            jbpm.task.hbm.xml.gz               jpdl-4.4.xsd.gz
jbpm.businesscalendar.cfg.xml.gz   jbpm.identity.cfg.xml.gz           jbpm.task.lifecycle.xml.gz         labels
jbpm.cfg.xml.gz                    jbpm.identity.hbm.xml.gz           jbpm.tx.hibernate.cfg.xml.gz       log4j.properties.gz
jbpm.console.cfg.xml.gz            jbpm.jboss.idm.cfg.xml.gz          jbpm.tx.jta.cfg.xml.gz             nohup.out.gz
jbpm.default.cfg.xml.gz            jbpm.jbossremote.cfg.xml.gz        jbpm.tx.spring.cfg.xml.gz
jbpm.default.scriptmanager.xml.gz  jbpm.jobexecutor.cfg.xml.gz        jbpm.variable.types.xml.gz
jbpm.execution.hbm.xml.gz          jbpm.jpdl.bindings.xml.gz          jbpm.wire.bindings.xml.gz
# cd ecnet
# ls
core  jms   rd    util
# cd core
# ls
util
# cd util
# pwd
/usr/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/rdnqa/WEB-INF/classes/ecnet/core/util
# ls
GridService.class.gz               MDPDFXMLParser.class.gz            PDFColumn.class.gz                 PDFXMLParser.class.gz
GridService.java.gz                MDPDFXMLParser.java.gz             PDFColumn.java.gz                  PDFXMLParser.java.gz
MDExcelXmlParser.class.gz          MasterDetailsPrintWriter.class.gz  PDFRow.class.gz                    RGBColor.class.gz
MDExcelXmlParser.java.gz           MasterDetailsPrintWriter.java.gz   PDFRow.java.gz                     RGBColor.java.gz
MDExcleWriter.class.gz             PDFCell.class.gz                   PDFWriter.class.gz                 xml2excel
MDExcleWriter.java.gz              PDFCell.java.gz                    PDFWriter.java.gz
#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rename` (it's designed for that). Just execute this command in the folder where the `*.gz` file are:

```
rename -n 's/\.gz$//' *.gz
```

This removed the .gz extension from all files that have a .gz extension. Output should look like this:

```
hibernate.queries.hbm.xml.gz renamed as hibernate.queries.hbm.xml
jbpm.businesscalendar.cfg.xml.gz renamed as jbpm.businesscalendar.cfg.xml
jbpm.cfg.xml.gz renamed as jbpm.cfg.xml
...
```

**Note:** If the output is as desired, execute the command without the `-n` switch. That switch causes `rename` **not to act, just show what files would have been renamed**.

Comment: Note that there are two tools called `rename`. The Perl version which you have supplied the syntax for and there's also a `util-linux` version which supports a simpler syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Following script might help:

```
for i in $(ls)
do
    mv $i ${i%.gz} 2> /dev/null
done
```

Basically it loops the files in directory and renames the files by removing 'gz' from the end.

Comment: You never should parse `ls` output in scripts. You can't rely on `ls`. It is meant for human eye and not for machine interpretation,

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and safest method would be to use find and tailor the command. E.g:

```
find . -type f -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c 'n=$1; mv -- "$n" "${n%.*}"' _ {} \;
```